# sonarqube plugin for vb6, plsql

Tags: vb.net, plsql, vb6, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Currently I am working on Jenkins and Sonar, to create a build-test-deploy pipeline. We have a project with vb6 coding and pl/sql files. I have configured sonar-scanner to perform the code quality on these source files.

However, when the scanner is connecting with SonarQube server post-scan, to upload report, I am getting an exception. This exception says, SonarQube plugin for vb6 needs license key.

When I checked the SonarQube configuration GUI, it shows licenses required for 3 of the plugins - VB6, VB.Net, PL/SQL.

I am not sure which license key needs to be supplied, for each.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can write to SonarQube, buy the licenses and then insert the keys in the corresponding fields beneath Administration->Licenses.

Comment: Thanks I just looked into Sonar-source plugin site, and it is a bit pricey. Is there any community version of VB6 code scanner?